# Best practices to move app from one developer to another

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I need to move an app from my current individual developer account to a corporation account.  I realize this cannot be done automatically, and that I just have to remove the app from sale in one account, then submit it in the other.

My question is, what is the prefered method of doing this to make it as seamless a possible for current users?  Should I alert them through a push notification?  Submit an app update that tells users they will have to redownload the app?

Any other tips on this transition?

This is a University app that is free and ranking doesn't matter as much as a paid app.

Comment: Try contacting Apple, they may me able to move it for you if you ask nicely.

Comment: There is an FAQ on iTunes Connect that specifically says it isn't possible.  Maybe since we are a University they might be nice...

Comment: Submitting an update with a changed name, where the update loudly advertises the new app with the old name and links to it in the App store, is one migration technique that has been seen in the App store.